# Cordova loading remote javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-maps, cordova

I am building iOS application with cordova/phonegap. Problem is that i can't load google maps, as it is external js script. I have looking for a few hours to find answer, but no luck.

However this is what I discovered:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This is working in browser and in xcode iOS simulator.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

This does not work in emulator and does not work on real device. Application doesn't load jquery, and fully breaks. Of course, this is working in browser, as expected.

I have

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in my config.xml ...

Also... putting this:

```
<img src="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery@2x.png">
```

somewhere in code... works OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution!

All external scripts must be included before all local scripts, specially before cordova.js!

That way i've got my google maps working in cordova iOS application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to add "http://" to your javascript code. Because cordova application not working on server, so there is no http or https protocol. It's not about access origin i guess.

Try this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you debug this application? What are you using for compile? And did you add internet permission to your application? Look at this one : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: Connection type is "wifi", replied by that navigator.connection.type link you mentioned...
I am using xcode for compile, there is some debuger console, but it says nothing... \